# How do I make GDB call a given function several times automatically?

Tags: gdb

I'd like to make GDB call a given function a large number of times automatically, say 100. Is there any command that will let me do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save this example script into a file say my_gdb_extensions

```
define fcall_n_times
 set $count = $arg0
 set $i=0
 while($i < $arg0)
  call $arg1
  set $i = $i + 1
 end
end
```

You can find more about gdb extensions [here.](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html)

```
$ gdb -x my_gdb_extensions <your_bin>
(gdb) start
(gdb) fcall_n_times 10 fact(3)
```

In the mentioned example `10` is the number of times you want to call the function. `fact(3)` is the function name with argument as 3.

Comment: You could also use `while ($i++ < $count)` and shorten the code a bit. Also, your `$count` is unused.