# debugging forks on BSD using gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, freebsd, bsd

Currently GDB has an issue following child processes after a fork. A work around I saw online is to use patch the following instruction :-

`call   0x8048740 <fork@plt>`

as follows :-

```
gdb$ set *(0x08048d1f+1)=0x90909090
gdb$ set *(0x08048d1f)=0x9090c033
```

Doing this sets the instructions as :-

```
xor    eax,eax
nop    
nop    
nop
```

As a result the code supposed to be executed as the child is executed by the parent, and im able to debug it. However, typing out the two step statements every time I have to debug the process is too tedious. Is there any way I can instruct gdb to patch those instructions everytime I attach to the process? Some kind of automation, limited as it may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to extend you GDB command list, using [gdb extensions](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html). Python scripts support is the latest development in GDB since 7.1 release. However looking at your requirement you don't need much scripting. You can use the simplest `define` command.

I had answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820788/how-do-i-make-gdb-call-a-given-function-several-times-automatically/8821137#8821137) some time back, you could use the same approach.